# SwiftUI watchOS play sound on speaker loud and continue music

Tags: swiftui, watchkit, avaudioplayer, watchos, avaudiosession

I want to create a watchOS App which play's a sound if I press a button. this sound should be played on the speaker with maximum volume. After the sound ends, the music should continue and the volume should go back to the volume before.

Currently I have this code, the music stops, the sound is playing on the speaker or bluetooth headphones, if they are connected.

```
try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default)        
try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)      
try? audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
audioPlayer?.play()
```

The sound should be played on the speaker, even if headphones are connected.

For iOS I found this code snippet, but it doesn't work in watchOS:

```
try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSession.PortOverride.speaker)
```

Unfortunately I have not found a solution yet.